# How do I remove the content of a div with class `node-inner` only if it contains `href="/test/profile"`?

Tags: css

I have html like this

```
<div class="node-inner">         
...
  <a href="/test/profile" title="View user profile.">test</a>
...       
</div>
```

I want to use `usercss` to remove the content of `<div class="node-inner">` if it contains `href="/test/profile"`.

My approach

```
.node-inner[class='node-inner'] {
 display: none;
}
```

filters everything. How do I remove the content of a div with class `node-inner` only if it contains `href="/test/profile"`?

Comment: Parent selectors don't exist in CSS

Comment: This would be a job for JavaScript, as you can't control parent selector in CSS

Comment: In addition, you're using an attribute selector on the `div`, but the attribute is on the link `<a>`. So currently nothing gets selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via JS

here's a quick example of doing that through jQuery:

```
$('.node-inner > [href="/test/profile"]').css('display', 'none')
```

[Fiddle (With jQuery)](https://jsfiddle.net/hw6ajvj7/1/)

And here how you can do it with vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.node-inner > [href="/test/profile"]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.display = "none";
})
```

[Fiddle (With Javascript)](https://jsfiddle.net/erynogsf/1/)

Comment: Not really picky: https://jsfiddle.net/hw6ajvj7/ - the second one is the only one working https://jsfiddle.net/22sh2wuo/

Comment: @FabienBiller Updated my answer :) https://jsfiddle.net/hw6ajvj7/1/ this should really do the job!